# HTTP request not sending

Tags: wifi, shields, http

so I have a wifi shield and I am sending a web request, but its not going through. I know it's not the server because the other function of the program works properly. My code is available on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/w9W3RGPi)

**EDIT:**

The request that is not working is on line 318

Comment: This is a meaningless question for Stack Exchange. You don't mention what shield, and you haven't posted any code (that will survive if Pastebin goes down. I'm closing it as not a real question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are lacking a space:

```
client.println((String)"GET /msg.php?action=send&ID=2&message=" += currentMessage += "HTTP/1.1");
                                                                                      ^
```

Your HTTP is running in to the content of your message ending up with a corrupt request. Also you are doing appending within your strings (`+=`) when you don't need to (`+` is all that is needed). In fact, you don't even need that - just do multiple prints and reduce the hammering your heap is getting. Oh, and don't forget to use `F()`:

```
client.print(F("GET /msg.php?action=send&ID=2&message="));
client.print(currentMessage);
client.println(F(" HTTP/1.1"));
```